Returning OneDrive for Business Documents path from reg query in batch file
I am trying to return the default file path for my documents on a machine that uses OneDrive for Business.
If I simply use the command prompt:
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Personal

Then I receive the correct response:
 C:\Users\*username*\OneDrive - *companyName*\Documents 1

But if I try to do this in a .cmd batch file using the following code:
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg.exe query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"')do (
set ValueValue=%%i
)
@echo Value Value = %ValueValue%

For some reason I get a slightly incorrect version of this, which appears to be a standard OneDrive path rather than OneDrive for business:
C:\Users\*username*\OneDrive

Is there anyway to correct this?

You are using two different registry paths.

Try for /f "tokens=2*" %%h in (… The third token ends at the space before the dash since you are using the default delimiters, so you need to ask for the prior delimiter and * which means the rest of the line. Since you are now selecting two tokens (2 and *) then %%h and %%i are assigned. See for/? for documentation or any number of SO articles. The quotes around ``Personal` appear to make no difference.

@Magoo this worked! Thank you. I don't fully understand why, previously I even tried looked at all three tokens, but this did the trick either way.

That's because token [1]=Personal   [2]=REG_EXPAND_SZ [3]=C:\Users*username*\OneDrive [4]=- [5]=companyName\Documents [6]=1. for/f just interprets the string using the default delimiter set (which includes space) and assigns a token for each string. Personal and *companyName*\Documents are simply strings - for does not know the meaning of each string

Can you not utilize the one of the OneDrive variables, %OneDrive%, %OneDriveCommercial% or %OneDriveConsumer%. %OneDrive% should be valid for the logged in user if you have only one OneDrive client on your PC or for the default one. Otherwise, %OneDriveConsumer% for the personal OneDrive, and %OneDriveCommercial% for OneDrive for Business, (yours). So for English Language, %OneDrive%\Documents, or %OneDriveCommercial%\Documents.
